# How expensive are calls to vector's back() method vs. storing the value vs. calling a method that returns an unpredictable value?

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-optimization

Wanting to figure out something to do with performance and compilation.
If someone uses multiple calls to `v.back()` instead of doing something like `T = v.back()` will the compiler optimize the code and why?
Theoretically, someone could implement a `back()` method that is random.
Is there something special about the implementation of back that makes it faster?

Comment: "Theoretically, someone could implement a back method that is random."  Random?  No, it's pretty well-defined, and must run in O(1).

Comment: @MaxBozzi Yes (I know that), I mean how would the compiler "know" that it always retrieves the same element and optimize for that? Is the compiler intimate with the language?

Comment: You're asking how the compiler could cache the result of the query `v.back()`?  While we assume that the vector is mutable, `back` isn't referentially transparent, so this is not simple to verify.  I don't know the details of any particular compiler optimizer, but some may trace the code to check.

Comment: Is this a local vector? Or can someone else update it between your calls to `v.back()`? If you know that the back element will stay unchanged for the duration of your series of calls to `v.back()` - I would cache it myself. If you are not sure - leave it to compiler to figure out. If the compiler doesn't cache it - may be you shouldn't have either.

Comment: Yes, it's not volatile. It is a sequential process running on a single core. Otherwise, the question is meaningless cause there no use in storing the value locally (the code behaves differently). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `v.back()` will not be cached if the compiler cannot see its implementation. Assuming it's inlined, though, the compiler can see which members of `v` contribute to the return value of `v.back()`. That's probably straightforward, something like `begin+size-1`. If neither of those two change, compilers will realize that they can do standard Common Subexpression Elimination on that expression.